# Difference between X.func and X.func( )

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I've come across many such situations where I have used in built functions or modules where the syntax is sometimes "X.func_name" and other times (X.func_name()".

For example : 
In Pandas "df.columns" gives names of all columns and throws and throws error if written by mistake as "df.columns()"  #TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable.

Also in Pandas, "count()", "min()" etc are written as df.count() | df.min()

I hope I have explained my question properly.

I believe it has something to do with the OOP concept of Class and it's member functions but I'd like a more in-dept understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to access an attribute `foo` of an object or module is always `.foo`.

An attribute may or may not be callable.  An `int` is not callable (it's just a number), but a function is callable.  To call a function `foo`, you use parentheses, possibly with parameters inside, e.g. `foo()` or `foo("bar")`.  Attempting to call something that is not callable will give you a `TypeError`.

So what syntax you use depends on whether the attribute is itself the value you want (e.g. an `int` or a `str`, or if it's a function that will return that value).  In your example, `columns` is itself an `int`, whereas `count` is a function that you need to call in order to get an `int`.

Note that it's possible in Python to wrap any value in a function, or to turn a function into a property (i.e. make an attribute that automatically calls a function to produce its value), but in general the convention is that if something requires some kind of dynamic computation it will be a function, and values that are predetermined will not require a function invocation to retrieve.

Comment: Thank You for the detailed answer. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The functions with parens are functions (actually class methods), which can take parameters and so on. Without parentheses, these are class variables.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank You.